# Extending iOS KMLViewer Sample to Handle KML NetworkLink Elements

Tags: ios, mapkit, kml

I am developing an iOS app that displays KML data over an MKMapView.

Apple's [KMLViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app has gotten me started.  Unfortunately, the KML data I am using relies heavily on linked files via the `NetworkLink`, `Link` and `href` KML elements, and KMLViewer's parser doesn't handle those.

I can probably figure out how to add such support, but before I go down that road I was wondering if anyone else has already done this, or if there is a better starting point than KMLViewer.

I've looked at [Simple KML](https://github.com/mapbox/Simple-KML), but it doesn't seem to support `NetworkLink` either.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how my investigations went:

1. I first extended the KMLViewer sample to support the additional elements I needed. The sample is not well suited to this: it is not organized the way a SAX-style parser should be, and the simplistic state machine really needs an overhaul if you want to add more stuff to it.
2. Next I tried the [Simple KML](https://github.com/mapbox/Simple-KML) library. It was easy to use, but it took 3500 milliseconds to parse the KML file I needed to parse, which was at least 3000 milliseconds longer than I would find acceptable. Also, Simple KML didn't support all the elements and attributes I needed, so I would have needed to extend it if I wanted to use it.
3. So, I finally just used [TBXML](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML), which was easy to use and which parsed the file in less than 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Would you mind helping me with this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335869/trying-to-parse-groundoverlay-inside-kml-file-in-swift . I really need help just like your problem.

Comment: @6245Htarwara It looks like your question has been deleted. FWIW, I haven't had to use KML for a few years, so I don't know much about it anymore.

Comment: I can parse KML now,like your suggestion.But,I used AEXML instead.Parse the <NetworkLink> of KML and get the image inside <href> and insert GroundOverlay style on my MKMapView.Thanks for your help.I get it solved so I deleted the question.