# Efficient KML Rendering as a MapKit overlay on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview, kml

Howdy all. I'm working on a project that will (ideally) require the rendering of large, complex KML files as an overlay/overlays on a MapKit MKMapView.

I've tried the KML parser that Apple's sample documentation provides, and it's rather incapable of performing as needed. Now, I'm wondering if anyone knows of another available solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to Apple's KMLViewer, it is using NSXMLParser, which is the slowest method. [image]

I'm not sure how fast you need, if TouchXML's performance is good enough for you, you should take a look at [Simple-KML](https://github.com/incanus/Simple-KML/). If that's not fast enough, I think you should implement your own parser based on [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html), but without validation + XPath support. (Let's assume Google's data is always rite ;-)

Edit:
Another user find Simple-KML is not fast enough and use TBXML directly also

[Extending iOS KMLViewer Sample to Handle KML NetworkLink Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248021/extending-ios-kmlviewer-sample-to-handle-kml-networklink-elements)

Comment: Not a complete solution, but a massive stepping stone. Plus, I like graphs. Answer accepted. Thank you good sir.